# How to revoke oauth2.1 token in spring boot new authorization server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-authorization-server, oauth-2.1

How to revoke the oAuth2 token in the spring boot new authorization server?

Also, where can we find all the endpoints of the authorization server?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoint to revoke [localhost:9000/oauth2/revoke](https://localhost:9000/oauth2/revoke)

We can pass either access/refresh token.

```
curl --location 'localhost:9000/oauth2/revoke' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=42ABBC9357A174FB206AAE7EAD3C0228' \
--data-urlencode 'token=eyJraWQiOiIwMWNjNWNjNi04YmQ0LTRjOTctYTZhZi01ZWY0Zjg5ZWY1YmIiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJiMjZhOTU5Yy0yYzA2LTQ0ODctYjNiNS1jYjNiNWYzODZmYTUiLCJhdWQiOiIxIiwibmJmIjoxNjc3OTQwMjk2LCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIl0sInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc3OTQwNTk2LCJpYXQiOjE2Nzc5NDAyOTZ9.ib1sDlAryine5rhBhq38_MCiNWDQeiDJpH7auXRKAuumi4lcDNb9jPFwlD2NcJyHYeCfGAaTG0KJTBg_FJTVcL579kxjwCawUT6TMRdK2QLVLE0IawDSg3j-GUGcpjdyyTvyg5y9Tdv_22NOcWega4ZguXLjhIGH-Fk7nVrApz5ARlAXoafg-09i_LMVDvs6T30xHD11xvWdx3QubiYUV_fzfbK6vNdE1mXzqXBA9hcf7u1HNVgUmzMQI97_y92Svp3DtVFc-v8bhn7hiBcFjERI7hxL57m-0RK0Qne0pvqcge7sb-OXB84F14EP8m2ic3eWwnJ1IjED5-OF0isW_Q' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=1' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=Thirumal'
```